# React Routers Switch is not updating when the route has changed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have a component where I list all categories news. The `Links` are in the other component but still in the Router. So when I change the link it changes but the content is not changing. I thought that it's because my `NewsFeed` component where I define my `Switch` with all routes is not updated.

It only works when I manually refreshing the page when the link is changed.

I wrapped the `NewsFeed` Component into `withRouter` HOC so it can know all the changes in Router. And it's really starting to know the changes but the content is not changed:

**NewFeed**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route, Switch, withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

import Category from './Category';

class NewsFeed extends React.Component {

    shouldComponentUpdate(newprops) {
        if(this.props.location.pathname !== newprops.location.pathname) {
            //The console logs different pathnames so it must update the Component
            console.log(this.props.location.pathname, newprops.location.pathname)
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="NewsFeedContainer">
                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path='/home' render={routeProps =>  <Category {...routeProps} />} />
                    <Route exact path='/bitcoin' render={routeProps => <Category {...routeProps} />} />
                    <Route exact path='/business' render={routeProps => <Category {...routeProps} />} />
                    <Route render={() => <div>Sorry, page is not found :(</div>} />
                </Switch>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default withRouter(NewsFeed);
```

**Header** Where Links are:

```
 import React from 'react';
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';

class Header extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <header>
                <NavLink to='/home'>Home</NavLink>
                <NavLink to='/bitcoin'>Bitcoin</NavLink>
                <NavLink to='/business'>Business</NavLink>
            </header>
        )
    }
}

export default Header;
```

**Category** The Routes Component

```
import React from 'react';

import ArticleCard from './ArticleCard';
import baseURL from '../helpers/baseURL';

const categories = {
    '/home': 'top-headlines?country=us',
    '/bitcoin': 'everything?q=bitcoin',
    '/business': 'top-headlines?country=us&category=business'
};

class Category extends React.Component {
    state = {
        newsData: [],
        category: categories[this.props.match.path],
        isLoading: true,
        isFailedToLoad: false,
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        fetch(baseURL(this.state.category))
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(json => json.articles)
            .then(articles => {
                this.setState({
                    newsData: articles,
                    isLoading: false,
                });
            })
            .catch(err => {
                this.setState({
                    isLoading: false,
                    isFailedToLoad: true
                })
            })
    }

    render() {
        const { newsData } = this.state;

        return (
            <div className='CategoryContainer'>
                {newsData.map((news, index) => (
                    <ArticleCard key={index} news={news} />
                ))}
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Category;
```

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react';

import './App.css';
import Header from './components/Header';
import NewsFeed from './components/NewsFeed';

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Header />
        <NewsFeed />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

The Router is defined in the `index.js` which wraps my `App` component.
It doesn't throw any errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this.

```js
<Route exact path='/home' render={routeProps =>  <Category {...routeProps} />} />
<Route exact path='/bitcoin' render={routeProps => <Category {...routeProps} />} />
<Route exact path='/business' render={routeProps => <Category {...routeProps} />} />
```

The reason for your issue is that you are using same component for all the routes. This means that the component is not unmounted upon route change. In other words, your componentDidMount is only executed once and won't execute on subsequent route change.

To solve the issue, you can force re-mount on route change by passing a key prop to the `Category` component which changes on every re-render.

**Like this**

```js
<Route exact path='/home' render={routeProps =>  <Category {...routeProps} key={Date.now()}/>} /> //<--- just provide an empty fun or Date.now()
```

Comment: The empty function doesn't worked but the Date.now worked very well! Thank you very much!

Comment: glad to hear it worked... updated the answer with date.now..